# When is the diamond operator, and when not?

Tags: java, generics, diamond-operator

Consider the following two lines of code:

```
final List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
final FileVisitor<Path> fv = new SimpleFileVisitor<>();
```

To me, they look quite similar. However, the second line is refused by the Java compiler (1.8) with the message "Cannot infer type arguments for SimpleFileVisitor<>".

Can anyone please explain, what's the problem?

Comment: The [`SimpleFileVisitor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/SimpleFileVisitor.html#SimpleFileVisitor--) constructor is protected. So you can't call it like that.

Comment: I get the error "'SimpleFileVisitor()' has protected access in 'java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor'" instead. The constructor is protected. You can't access it. I doubt deleting the diamond make the error go away... so I'm not sure why you think the problem is about the diamond.

Comment: It is still the **diamond operator**, I am stressing this because of the title of your question.

Comment: It is more that the automatic type-inference, that the diamond operator is using, has some limits as well. Java can not always infer the type automatically, sometimes you have to specify it manually. Sometimes it can infer it but its not the type you want, then you also have to specify it manually. And in your particular case the problem is rather that the code is invalid and hence Java also can not infer the type. So it is just a follow-up problem of the other issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you may get the error message `Cannot infer type arguments` because your syntax is correct, except for the fact that as many have said already, the class `java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor` has only one constructor which is `protected`:

```
protected SimpleFileVisitor() {
}
```

This means that only children of this class can initialize an instance of `SimpleFileVisitor`, and that's why your code doesn't compile.

I don't know this class, but by a quick look at the code I guess they simply expect you to extend it first (or use an already existing extension coming from somewhere else), and then use it the implementations of the `FileVisitor` interface.

If you don't have a concrete child class to use and want to create your own `MySimpleFileVisitor`:

```
public class MySimpleFileVisitor<T> extends SimpleFileVisitor<T> {
    public MySimpleFileVisitor() {
        super(); //<-- here you have the right to call the protected constructor of SimpleFileVisitor
    }
}
```

... you will then be able to instantiate your class and use the already implemented methods like this:

```
FileVisitor<Path> fv = new MySimpleFileVisitor<>(); //<-- here you will be able to correctly infer parameter type as you do in your List example
fv.visitFile(file, attrs); //<-- here you enter the method implemented inside SimpleFileVisitor
```